# Calculating transmission time between 2 nodes on a network

Tags: networking, transmission

Hosts A and B are each connected to a switch S via 100-Mbps links as shown above. The
propagation delay between Host A and switch S is 20 μ second and the propagation delay between switch S and Host B is 25 μ second. S is a store-and-forward device that can send and receive bits simultaneously; it begins retransmitting a received packet 35 μ second after it has finished receiving it (if it can).
Calculate the total time in milliseconds required to transmit 4000 bytes from host A to host B.

Comment: What is your question? Simply copying and pasting homework problems here is not OK.

Comment: Considering the part where Host A transmits 4000 bytes to the switch.
I just want to know which formula to use to calculate the transmission time from A to the switch